# Getting page crash error on running tests in extra small screen size in selenium 4 - spock groovy framework

Tags: selenium, crash, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

**Issue**

We noticed recently that our tests that use XSMALL((150..767), 1000) screen size crash in HEADLESS mode for Chrome browser (although these tests pass when run in non-headless mode) .

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted
> because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading
> status from tab crashed  Session info: headless chrome=99.0.4844.51)

Once you get this error, all the remaining tests in the test suite fail with the following error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id

Another observation is that this happens specifically when you try to resize the chrome browser from Large to XSMALL screen size. We are using Selenium 4 and tested with chrome versions 97, 98 and 99. Is anyone else facing similar issue and do you have suggestions on how to fix it?

**What we tried**

At our end, we tried couple of solutions mentioned online like increasing shared memory size, setting chrome options “--disable-dev-shm-usage” and”—no-sandbox” but nothing worked for us so far.

**Sample Code**

```html
def "should render Home Page "() {
    given:
    String homePageURL = url +  lang

    when:
    webDriver.get(homePageURL)
    WebDriverUtil.setBrowserSizeWithSafeMaxWidth(webDriver, ScreenSize.XSmall)

    then:
    Assert homePage.getAd
```

Comment: What do you think headless does for ui.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan the problem is we don't know what is the difference between headless and non-headless that makes it difficult to figure out what can we do for solution.